# Catching error messages from a NodeJS express application using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have an application using NodeJS in backend and specifically Express framework to serve API routes. My client side is written in ReactJS, making use of `axios` to make API requests.

First time using `axios` package, and i can't find how to access error messages from the response.

My API returns as error responses:

```
res.status(404).send({ error: 'Error Message' });
```

In `axios` i have:

```
axios.post('/api/users', newUser)
  .then((user) => {
    console.log(`User created: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Error : ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
  });
```

`` console.log(`Error : ${JSON.stringify(err)}`) `` prints:

```
{
  "message": "Request failed with status code 404",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 404\n    at createError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:13853:15)\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:14074:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:13328:7)",
  "config": {
    "url": "/api/users",
    "method": "post",
    "data": "someData",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxx",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1
  }
}
```

I can't find nowhere in that `err` object the response message from the server, i have even tried:

```
res.status(404).json({ error: 'Error Message' });
```

with no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [this comment](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1369#issuecomment-366741524), try accessing `err.response` in the `catch` block.

Comment: Thank you, could find that in err.response.data. Everything express js sends as response is located in data object

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The `err.response` would have an object `{ error: 'Error Message' }` so you can access that using `err.response.error`. also make sure `err.response.error` exists because if it doesn't and you try to access it will throw an error inside the catch saying `err.response.error is undefined`

```
axios.post('/api/users', newUser)
  .then((user) => {
    console.log(`User created: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`);
  }).catch((err) => {
   if(err.response.error)
    console.log(`Error : ${JSON.stringify(err.response.error)}`);
  });
```